# Bizarre Numpy sorting behavior

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

It seems that NumPy argsort works lexicographically on floats:

```
npSorted = np.array([[ "a", 12],
  ["B", 8 ],
  ["D", -0.96605562],
  [ "e", -0.28283675],
  ["F",  0.22764316],
  ["T",  0.27752806],
  ["G",  0.36523876],
  ["H",  0.50737573],
  [ "ME",  0.93213482]])

npSorted = npSorted[npSorted[:, 1].argsort()]

for sortedStock in npSorted:
  print(sortedStock[0], ": ", sortedStock[1])
```

Result is:

```
e :  -0.28283675
D :  -0.96605562
F :  0.22764316
T :  0.27752806
G :  0.36523876
H :  0.50737573
ME :  0.93213482
a :  12
B :  8
```

So how should I sort, to get 0.5 < 8 < 12?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be using NumPy arrays for heterogeneous data. `npSorted[:, 1].dtype` is a string type because NumPy is converting your floats into strings to make the datatype uniform.

Comment: Or at least, if you're going to put heterogeneous data in an array, you should use a structured dtype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like what @Tomothy32 said, don't use heterogenous data. Here's what you can do to fix it. add .astype(np.float) before sorting

```
npSorted = npSorted[npSorted[:, 1].astype(np.float).argsort()]
# D :  -0.96605562
# e :  -0.28283675
# F :  0.22764316
# T :  0.27752806
# G :  0.36523876
# H :  0.50737573
# ME :  0.93213482
# B :  8
# a :  12
```

Comment: @SteveBrown I believe you need to vote first, then accept the answer